# Dealing with versioning in couchbase

Tags: c#, couchbase

My problem is, I start with a class like this:

```
public class MyType {
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

I then go and store this on couchbase with the client library, for example:

```
var client = new CouchbaseClient("mybucket");
var instance = new MyType()
{
    PropertyOne = "1",
    PropertyTwo = "2"
};

var key = "MyType_" + Guid.NewGuid();

client.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, key, instance);
```

But I then have the need to refactor my type thus changing the signature:

```
public class MyType {
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

So the problem comes when I try to deserialize old data (before the change) and new data which uses the new signature using:

```
var oldSignatureVersion = clientB.Get<MyType>("MyType_maybe_signature_1_or_2");
var newSignatureVersion = clientB.Get<MyType>("MyType_maybe_signature_1_or_2");
```

I don't know how to deal with this without making the code really ugly, whats the best approach here?

Thanks